# API to get water body names by coordinates

Tags: coordinates, geocoding, software-recommendations, reverse-geocoding

We have some geometry records - water bodies in a DB which does not have name. I have tried to use Google Geocoding to extract them but it seems that it is more suitable for addresses. Is there any API to get water body names by coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You can try BigDataCloud's reverse geocoding API: https://www.bigdatacloud.com/geocoding-apis/reverse-geocode-to-city-api

This API is based on the administrative/non-administrative boundary and provides the name of the smallest region which can be land or water.